# How to fetch particular value from database in another div ? 

Tags: jquery, perl, lightbox

I tried everything what I could do. My motive is to:

Let me introduce to my objective and code. I have `main.pl` which consists of following code:
This code is fetching datas from database. And it's working fine.

```
 while($query->fetch()) {
        print $cgi_plat->start_form(
                -id=>'plat',
                #-method=>'POST',
                #-action=>'plat.pl',
                -bgcolor => 'white',
            );

         print $cgi_plat->Tr(
             $cgi_plat->td(
                     $cgi_plat->hidden(   -id=>'code',
                                          -value=>$code)
                                       )

                           ),
                      $cgi_plat->td( 
                          $cgi_plat->submit( -id=>'edit',
                                             -name=>'edit',
                                             -value=>'edit',
                                           )
                                   ),
          );

          print $cgi_plat->end_form;
 }
```

jQuery handles the submit function.It's also working fine.Here is the code:.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#edit').click(function(){
    alert("edit");
            var code=jQuery('#code').val();
    var edit=jQuery('#edit').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'plat.pl',
            data : {'code':code, 'edit':edit},
            success: function(msg){
                    jQuery('#lightbox').fadeIn(1000);
                    jQuery('#lightboxbg').fadeIn(1000);
            }
         });
return false;

});
```

Now the  problem arises in this section. Here how to get the value sent by jQuery in div:lightbox .When I simply use require `plat.pl` in div section.It doesn't work.I also tried  using function.It doesn't work either.

```
 print '<div  id="lightboxbg" > </div>'; 
   print '<div  id="lightbox">';
   #Here I want to output values corresponding to $code when submit button 
     is clicked. Here,it takes the last value of $code which seems reasonable.But I
    want that value of $code. 

    print   '</div>';
  print '</div>';
```

Comment: Show the full code of `main.pl` and `plat.pl`, and since the `main.pl` output apparently depends on a database, also show an example full HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

as daxim says we need to see all the code to understand how it fits together, but from your description "Here I want to output values corresponding to $code when submit button is clicked. Here, it takes the last value of $code which seems reasonable. But I want that value of $code." it sounds like $code is my'd outside the while loop when it should be in the while loop.

what is the value of $code in the hidden input field and what do you expect it to be?